# Shimming with Microsoft Fakes and a static, generic method

Tags: unit-testing, stub, microsoft-fakes, shim

I need to shim a static generic method for a unit test. However, I can't seem to get Fakes to create the shim object. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

In particular, I want to shim Newtonsoft's JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each return type that you would expect register a delegate like so:

With this code in the Unit Test:

```
using (var context = ShimsContext.Create())
{
    ShimJsonConvert.DeserializeObjectOf1String<SomeJSonObject>(s => new SomeJSonObject() { Name = "Foo" });

    SomeJSonObject o = ConsoleApplication3.Program.Deserialize();
    Assert.IsNotNull(o);
    Assert.AreSame(o.Name, "Foo");
}
```

And this code under test:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeJSonObject>("");
```

It works as expected for me.

If needed also register the other overloads. So if you're using some of the other overloads, you must also register their corresponding delegates on the Shim:

[image: Other Overloads]

Like:

```
ShimJsonConvert.DeserializeObjectOf1String<SomeJSonObject>(s => new SomeJSonObject() { Name = "Foo" });
ShimJsonConvert.DeserializeObjectOf1StringJsonConverterArray((s, convertors) => new SomeJSonObject() {Name = "Bar"});
ShimJsonConvert.DeserializeObjectOf1StringJsonSerializerSettings((s, settings) => new SomeJSonObject() { Name = "Bar" });
```

Comment: That worked. Previously, I was creating unit tests and had to shim other generic methods of instance classes. I wasn't finding the methods in intellisense. I found this article: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/erix99/archive/2012/08/09/who-test-generic-methods-using-microsoft-fakes.aspx. After employing the workaround mentioned here, everything worked out fine. Can you please tell me the deal is with FakesDelegates?

Comment: Actually, this isn't working. I thought it was, but I had a configuration wrong. When stepping through the code, it is stepping through the actual code and not the shim

Comment: I updated with a little more info. If this still isn't working, please share the code of your unit test.